# Scala code to check whether kafka broker (server) is available or not

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

How to check whether Kafka server is available or not available.

I have tried below scala code 
-Producer API.

```
  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "hworker.dev.m.private:7667")
  props.put("acks", "1")
  props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
  props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer")
```

May I know how check the above bootstrap server is available or not.

Comment: Rather than say "I want", can you please [edit] your question to include what you've tried, and what uncaught errors you're getting otherwise when a broker is unavailable? FWIW, you should be using more than one server address in that property

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Kafka [AdminClient](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html) like below. It will return the TimeOutException if the server is not responding.

```
private static final TIMEOUT_MS = 5000;           
 try (AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(props)) {
            client.listTopics(new ListTopicsOptions().timeoutMs(TIMEOUT_MS)).listings().get();
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            LOG.error("Kafka is not available, timed out after {} ms", TIMEOUT_MS);
            return;
        }
```

P.S. *It will work for Kafka 0.11+ version.*

Comment: it is not working - I am getting below error- 1. Cannot resolve overloaded method 'create'. 2. Cannot resolve symbol props  3. Cannot resolve symbol static 4. Cannot resolve symbol TIMEOUT_MS.